# returning a generic type with template functions

Tags: c++, templates

I'm new to using templates and I want to make a function that returns generic types. I made a very simple template as such

```
enum tag { SHORT, INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE };
template <typename T>
T get_val(tag t){
    switch (t) {
    case SHORT: return .. //returns a short;
    case INT: return .. //returns a int;
    case FLOAT: return .. //returns a float;
    case DOUBLE: return .. //returns a double;
    }
}
```

the problem is that floats and doubles are returned as integer numbers. so I wonder why this happens and if there's a way I can use it properly.

Comment: You can't have your return type depend on the value of a function parameter, it is a fundamental limit

Comment: I would highly recommend using C++'s `variant` or `any` structure (C++17, but backported to C++11) if you can, which allows you to access values if the type matches. You can't do this, but you can get somewhat close. If not, you can pass the variant to a function and call the proper overload within the switch statement (where the type is deduced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not use a different return type using a `switch` statement like that.

However, if the input to `get_val` is known at compile time, you can use template metaprogramming techniques to get what you need.

```
enum tag { SHORT, INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE };

template <tag t> struct return_type_chooser;

template <> struct return_type_chooser<SHORT>
{
   using type = short;
};

template <> struct return_type_chooser<INT>
{
   using type = int;
};

template <> struct return_type_chooser<FLOAT>
{
   using type = float;
};

template <> struct return_type_chooser<DOUBLE>
{
   using type = double;
};

template <tag t>
typename return_type_chooser<T>::type get_val()
{
   ...
}
```

You can use:

```
get_val<SHORT>()
```

but not

```
get_val(SHORT)
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

If the input to `get_val` is known only at run time, [`std::any` (C++17)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html) should work as the return type.

Comment: I think I understand what you say; However, the parameter of get_val is dependent on the input of the user

Comment: A variant is much more likely to be what the OP wants, since it will be a limited subset of types rather than complete type erasure. Using `std::variant` or `boost::variant` with `get_if` would provide the safety the OP desires, and allow them to call function overloads of the correct type for known subset of types.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, Neither `std::variant` nor `bool::variant` is a viable solution since the return type must be known at compile time.

Comment: I think you're confused about how to use `std::variant`. You can't return a custom type, and with any you can return any type, but it also makes it very difficult to access and adds a lot of overhead. For this usecase, defining a variant with known possible types, returning the variant and then having a public API that takes the variant and uses `get_if` to access the correct type is more efficient, and a better use-case than `any`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing this with a variant and runtime checks for the type among a limited subset of possible types:

Use a public interface taking a variant with an enum for the correct type (this is a naive version, you should really use `std::variant` and `get_if`):

```
enum variant_type
{
    variant_null,
    variant_int,
    variant_float,
    variant_double,
}


class variant
{
public:
    // Add constructors with the correct type for the
    // underlying storage
    variant() = default;
    variant(int x);
    variant(float x);
    variant(double x);

    // ensure you can check for empty variants and check the type
    explicit operator int() const;
    explicit operator float() const;
    explicit operator double() const;
    explicit operator bool() const;
    variant_type type() const;

private:
    variant_type type_ = variant_null;
    void* data_ = nullptr;
};
```

Then, add many custom function or method overloads that allow you to choose the correct method at runtime:

```
class my_handler
{
public:
    my_handler(const variant& v)
    {
        switch (v.type()) {
            case variant_null;
                open(nullptr);      break;
            case variant_int;
                open(int(v));       break;
            case variant_float;
                open(float(v));     break;
            case variant_double;
                open(double(v));    break;
        }
    }

private:
    void open(std::nullptr_t nullp);
    void open(int x);
    void open(float x);
    void open(double x);
};
```

This allows you to have a public interface that is generic for a limited subset of types, but that allows you to avoid having to know the correct type at compile-time.

This can all be done much more idiomatically using `std::variant` and `get_if` rather than writing your own custom variant class. I just this as an (inefficient) example of how many libraries (like the Windows API and Qt) have implemented their own.